# javascript: Avoid browser scrolling back to top on content insertion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought this would be very easy to solve, but I can`t seem to find a solution anywhere.
It's a very annoying javascript 'feature?'. Every time I add content to a div the document gets scrolled back to top. How can I avoid this annoying behaviour?

```
n = 0;
function addContent() {
    div = document.getElementById('content');
    for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        n++;
        div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + n + '<br />';
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="addContent()">more content</a>
```

Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/hQP2q/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that ,

When you click on the anchor link , the onclick event handler registered for that element get fired.

Now the default behavior for the anchor tag is to navigate to the href attribute of its own.

In your case both happens , so the url is navigated to "#".  The "#" is acting as a bookmark , so browser will look for any html element which has an id , same as the string after the # in the url.

So the solution to fix this problem is , in your onclick handler , pass the event object and when the onclick handler get executed, Just use the event object to prevent the default action of the element click behaviour.

so the code will be like when modified.

```
<script>
     n = 0;
    function addContent(e) {
        div = document.getElementById('content');
        for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            n++;
            div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + n + '<br />';
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="addContent(event)">more content</a>
```

see the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/uKrpH/2/embedded/result/

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what was going on on my minified example. And I couldn't see it. But that's not what is going on in my site. At least now I know where I need to check. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue.. When I clicked on an icon in a table, broswer changed content of cell and scrolled to top of page. I tried to add "return false;" and the issue is gone.

```
<a href="#" onclick="addContent(); return false;">more content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
<a href="#" onclick="addContent()">more content</a>
```

with

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="addContent()">more content</a>
```

OR
try:

```
<a href="#" onclick="addContent();return false;">more content</a>
```

Another option is to add an id to the href like this: See [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hQP2q/1/)

```
<a id="link" href="#link" onclick="addContent()">more content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Solution should be giving an #id which doesn't exist on your page.

e.g.

```
<a href="#dontscroll" onclick="addContent()">more content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead i would do it jQuery way: http://jsfiddle.net/hQP2q/3/

```
<a href="#">more content</a> // <----i just removed the onclick from here

<script type="text/javascript">
        n = 0;

        function addContent() {
            div = document.getElementById('content');
            for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                n++;
                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + n + '<br />';
            }
        }
        $(function() { //<----------------------i would do it here.
            $('a').click(function(e) {
                addContent();
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```